# multi coin solo mining

Tags: solo-mining

I'm wondering about switching coins while solo mining?

Does switching before I block is mined effect the odds of getting a block reward, or is it always essentially chance??
For example, if I mine for 30 minutes on Feathercoin, then jump to Litecoin, when I come back to Feathercoin will there be any accumulated value in the wallet?

Am I ever starting over, or is it always chance?

By the way, I'm using a node stratum pool, so it's direct connect to the wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every single attempt at mining a block is independent of every other attempt and has precisely the same chance of succeeding. There is no intermediate work to save or lose.

Comment: How does pool mining effect these chances, when that request variable difficulty? Does that produce potentially more or less of a chance?

Comment: With pool mining, you're trying to mine shares, not blocks. Your odds of success are much higher, but otherwise it's all the same. Each attempt at mining a share is independent and there is no intermediate work to save or lose.